# how to call setter method in angular

Tags: angular

I want to update my form using setter method.. Where should i call setter method?
Here is my component.ts code

```
export class UpdateZoneComponent implements OnInit {
 profileForm: FormGroup
 products: any;
 h: number;
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private route: 
ActivatedRoute) { }
 ngOnInit() {
this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  zone_name: [''],
  zone_id: ['']
});
```

//Here id is coming from a component which has click event

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(routeParam => {
  const id = +routeParam.get('id');
  console.log(id)
  this.h = id
})
this.http.get("http://192.168.8.219:8835/zonedata/" + this.h).subscribe(
  (res: any) => {
    console.log(res)
    const response = res.data;
    const nameZone = res.data.zone_name;
    console.log(nameZone)
  }
)
}
```

// here we want to update the zone name using setter method

```
set zone_name(name) {
console.log("hello")
let strg = this.profileForm.get("zone_name").setValue(name);
console.log(strg)
}
save(value: any) {
console.log(value)
const url = `${"http://192.168.8.219:8835/zonedata"}${this.h}`;
this.http.put(url, this.products).subscribe((dataa) => {
  console.log(dataa)
  this.zone_name();
})

}
}
 <form [formGroup]="profileForm" #zoneData (ngSubmit)="save(profileForm.value)">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="zname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Zone Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 txt-box">
                        <input type="text" name="zname" formControlName="zone_name" 
                              id="zoneName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter"  
                         [value]="zone_name" >
                            <p style="color: white">{{zone_name}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class=" col-md-10">
                        <button type="submit"  class="a-btns btn btn-success">Save</button>
                      </div>
                </div>
               </form>
```

Comment: as you are using a reactive form, you don't certainly need to update the form fields. Values gets updated automatically. you will get every change you do.

`this.profileForm.valueChanges.subscribe((res) => {`
             `console.log(this.profileForm.value);`
   `});`

Comment: Neel, take account Sibabrat comments, BTW, you use `this.zone='what-ever'` to execute the "function" `set zone_name(name) {...}` -in the function, name gets the value "what-ever"

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the reactive form in angular, you don't certainly need to update the form fields. Value gets updated automatically. you will get every change you do.

add this in your constructor and you will find the changes you made to your reactive form.

```
constructor() {
  this.profileForm.valueChanges.subscribe((res) => {
     console.log(this.profileForm.value);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
this.http.put(url, this.products).subscribe((dataa) => {
if(dataa)
setNameZone(dataa);
 }) 
setNameZone(val)
{this.profileForm.controls.zone_name.setValue(val);
}
```